# How do I insert month/year on multiple sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add the month and year for the previous month in A2 of multiple sheets without selecting each individual sheet. I'm setting up a template to run reports every month.

I've searched, but I can't locate examples that are similar and loop instead of selecting each sheet.

```
Sub dateins()
' Date as Mo and year. Current month minus one.
Dim dash As Worksheet, daily As Worksheet, mon As Worksheet
Dim Thisday As Date, Rptmon As Date, ws As Worksheet

Set dash = Sheets("Dashboard")
Set daily = Sheets("Daily")
Set mon = Sheets("Monthly")
Thisday = Date

Rptmon = DateAdd("m", -1, Thisday)
Rptmon = Format(Thisday, "mmmm yyyy")
   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Select Case ws.Name
     Case "dash", "daily", "mon"
        If ws.Range("A2") = "" Then
            ws.Range("A2").Replace What:="", Replacement:=Rptmon
        End If
   End Select
  Next ws

End Sub
```

This loop does not insert the date on any of the sheets. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What are the full case-sensitive names of the worksheets you want to apply the date to?

Comment: "Dashboard"," Daily" ,"Monthly"

Comment: I changed to the full case-sensitive names and it worked beautifully! Thank you for the simple correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Select Case is looking at the worksheet names, not the variables you've assigned to the worksheet objects.

```
Sub dateins()

    ' Date as Mo and year. Current month minus one.
    Dim dash As Worksheet, daily As Worksheet, mon As Worksheet
    Dim Thisday As Date, Rptmon As Date, ws As Worksheet

    Set dash = Sheets("Dashboard")
    Set daily = Sheets("Daily")
    Set mon = Sheets("Monthly")
    Thisday = Date

    Rptmon = DateAdd("m", -1, Thisday)
       For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Select Case ws.Name
          Case "Dashboard", "Daily", "Monthly"
            If ws.Range("A2") = "" Then
                ws.Range("A2") = Rptmon
                ws.Range("A2").numberformat = "mmmm yyyy"
            End If
       End Select
      Next ws

End Sub
```

You want to assign a true date to A2 and let the cell format display the *"mmmm yyyy"*.